# How to call mixin function in middleware

Tags: vue.js, middleware, mixins, nuxt.js

How can I call mixin function in middleware with NUXT.js?

I am trying to do this:

```
export default function(context) {
  // init auth token from the local store or cookies
  context.initAuth(context.req)

  if (!context.store.getters['sessionStorage/isAuthenticated']) {
    context.redirect("/login")
  }
}
```

where `initAuth()` function is located in the `plugins/auth.js` mixin file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't call mixin in middleware, because mixin is something related to vue-component instanse. 
Did you mean you want to call a function? Then you doing it right, except you should [inject](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins#inject-into-context) your function into the context.